# Do I need to re-generate SSH RSA public keys or re-import them again in case my LDAP password changes/expires?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I've took a liking to authenticating with RSA keys a few days ago and imported the keys to the hosts I have been connecting to.

However, my company's policy expires passwords every once in a while; the question is - do I need to re-generate or re-import public keys once it happens?

If yes, are there ways to simplify / automate the process?

Comment: SSH keys don't have expiry: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/66936/54387

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to reimport your keys

They will be valid until removed from .ssh/authorized_keys file.

In case your pam-ldap is setup to disable the user once the password has expired, you won't be able to login with the key until your user re-enabled (changing LDAP password).

Answer (score 1):

No you don't have to regenerate your public/private key pair, unless your private key is compromised.

There is nothing that creates a permanent connection between your password and the key-pair, the only thing you might need your password for is when you copy the public key to the server for the first time (using ssh-copy-id)

Comment: Thank you! I am going to accept fireto's answer to promote his activity on the site (and as you already have stellar reputation :)).

Comment: @EugeneA with the additional information about re-enabling his answer is somewhat more complete as well.